# returning a tuple from a dictionary, I need the key but am getting the value instead

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I have a dictionary `myDict`

```
{'1': 5, '2': 15, '3', 50}
```

I have a targetNumber of `12`

I'm using this code to find the number closest to `12` in `myDict`

```
answer = key, value = min(myDict.items(), key=lambda (_, v): abs(v - targetNumber))
```

`answer` returns `('2', 15)`

That's the key/value that I want, but what I really need now is the `2`.
When I print `myDict[key]`, it returns `15`

How can I return what I believe *was* the key, but now that it is in that tuple, i'm not sure exactly what i'm dealing with.

I'd like to end up with:

`2`

Comment: I don't understand... you've got it in answer... it's ``answer[0]``...

Comment: you're right, thank you!

Comment: it's ``myDict[answer[0]]``

Comment: int(key) ?  Your question is very unclear, you have the two pieces you want right in key and value.

Comment: I didn't understand how to get the pieces, I do now; I appreciate your help folks

Comment: `answer, forget_this_value =min(myDict.items(), key=lambda (_, v): abs(v - targetNumber))`  - its called decomposition - you decompose the tuple-result into 2 variables - you do not need key and value ... for that - you can directly use `answer` - the 15 is stored in `foget_this_value`

Comment: @yodish and `forget_this_value` (in Patrick Artner's answer) is traditionally sent to `_` in python, which you already saw in the `lambda` function, for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack "answer":

Key, Value = answer

or use

Key = Answer[ 0 ]

Value = Answer{ 1 ]